# bootstrap grid system to format picture

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i was using bootstrap grid system to format picture like:

[image]

this is my code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well"><img  src="..." class="img-responsive"">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well"><img  src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well"><img  src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the picture to be responsive so I put `class="img-responsive"` on the `<img>`

```
<img  src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

but end up like the right picture. if i dont use `class="img-responsive"` the image will show on full resulution. how i fix this? (please give me a easy explanation because i'm a noob :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply **CSS Flexbox** rules on `.row` & `.col-*-*`. I've used some custom classes (all the `.col-*-*` has a class called `.item`). Like:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item.left {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item.left {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item.left .well {
  width: 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.item.left .well img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="item left col-sm-4">
        <div class="well"><img  src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="well"><img  src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="well"><img  src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the code working greatly but, when i test is with same resulution picture(1920x1080), the result is not good. so i must make my picture in proper size? like in the example?

Answer (score 0):

You should use following `HTML` structure as you need left and right columns having equal width:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        // content....
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
       // content....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="well"><img  src="..." class="img-responsive">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="well"><img  src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
      <div class="well"><img  src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```